# $f(x) = \sqrt{x^{2}+1}-1$ (Loss of Significance)

Tags: numerical-algorithms, error-estimation

Let us say that I want to compute $f(x) = \sqrt{x^{2}+1}-1$ for small values of $x$ in a Marc-32 architecture. I can avoid loss of significance by rewriting the function

$$f(x)=\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-1\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+1}\right)=\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+1}$$

Even though I can solve the problem, I do not know/understand why the solution has avoid the loss of significance?

Comment: When $x$ is small $x^2$ will be smaller. That's not a problem on its own. You can represent some small positive numbers using negative exponents. The denominator is the sum of two positive numbers that are close to $1$. Namely $1$ and $\sqrt{x^2+1}$. Since you are adding, their most significant digit doesn't cancel. Instead they add to give you $2$. So, after the sum, the exponent only needs to increase by $1$ to normalize the result. Then you divide $x^2/(\sqrt{x^2+1}+1)$, which is close to dividing $x^2$ by $2$. The most significant digit of $x^2$ might move to the right, but only ...

Comment: ... no more than two positions. So, to normalize the result the exponent will have to decrease the exponent by $2$ at most. Now, compare to computing $\sqrt{x^2+1}-1$. These two numbers are very close but we are subtracting. Their most significant digit will cancel. If $x^2$ is very small. The distance between the most significant digit of $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ and the next non-zero digit can be large. The worst case is when $x^2$ is smaller than the machine epsilon. Then you will get $x^2+1=1$. This means that to normalize $\sqrt{x^2+1}-1$ you might need to decrease the exponent substantially.

Comment: In the worst case you get $\sqrt{x^2+1}-1=0$, when $x^2$ is smaller than the machine epsilon.

Comment: Great points @plop
Let me write what I have come up with (bear with me, it might be a bit lengthy):

Comment: @plop 

For me it is not clear with the user "gnasher729" point was, and what he wanted me to do with the $\epsilon = 10^{-10}$. 

But this is what I have come up with. Let us say that we have a 6-decimal machine. And let us assume that it have a double-length register. Let us say that I want to calculate $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}-1$ for $x=10^{-6}$. The calculations in the register will be $f(x) = \sqrt{10^{-12}+1} - 1  = 1.000000000001 - 1 = 0.000000000001 $. Now this is sent to the main memory which is 6-decimal word length. The rounded results will then be $0.0$. So $f(x)=0$ for small $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that due to rounding errors, when you try to calculate the square root of $x^2 + 1$ you actually get the square root plus $\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$. Assume that $\epsilon = 10^{-10}$ and $x = 10^{-6}$. Perform the calculations and write down the results.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by calculating? Should I calculate it by **hand** first using $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-1$ and the using $f(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}+1}$, and then compare it?

Comment: @Xenusi By hand or not by hand is not crucial. What is important is that you need to compute each in the floating point arithmetic that you have at hand. This means that after each arithmetic involved you need to re-normalize and round the exact result according to the sizes that your mantissa and exponent can hold. Pay particular attention to what happens after the last operation (the subtraction) in $\sqrt{x^2+1}-1$ when $x$ is small.

Comment: Doing things by hand (pen and paper, or using a pocket calculator, or a spreadsheet, or a computer program) is very useful to first show you _what_ happens - which is a precondition for understanding _why_ it happens.

Comment: @gnasher729 But I honestly do not know what you what me to do? Especially what you want me to do with the epsilon.